# Problem with web3.py + pyinstaller

Tags: web3.py, python

I used web3.py to create a program, and turned it into an exe with pyinstaller, but now I am getting this error when I try to run the exe:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "web3\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "web3\main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ens\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ens\async_ens.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ens\base_ens.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ens\utils.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 385, in exec_module
  File "ens\_normalization.py", line 57, in <module>
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\SELCUK~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI166402\\ens\\specs\\normalization_spec.json'
```

The given directory path is wrong, so it's normal that this gives an error, but I have no way of fixing this as this is a problem from inside the web3 module. Has anyone ever came across this error?

Comment: Also wanted to add, the code works fine when not compiled into an exe so it's not a code related problem. It's a compilation related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use web3==5.31.4

not use web3>=6.*

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Version 6.6.0 had a problem with the necessary json files not being included. If you specify 6.6.1 you should be fine. Support for v5 is due to stop in August.

Answer (score 0):

*pyinstaller* needs a manual addition utilizing the `--add-data` flag. This question has been answered before for similar issues:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62017384/adding-json-files-to-an-exe-file-using-pyinstaller